# R: Compute a new dataframe column from a function that calls functions

Tags: r

I'm trying to compute a new column for a dataframe using a multi-argument
function. When that function is simple, everything is fine. When that
functions calls another function, things go awry.

## PART 1: The dataset of interest.

```
# The goal is to transform Foo into a new column.
df <- data.frame(
   Year =c(1901,1901,1900,1902),
   Month=c(   2,   1,   2,   1),
   Foo  =c(   1,   2,   3,   4)
)

# This simple multi-arg transform works fine.
Foo2Baz <- function(year, month, foo) {
  return(year + month + foo)
}
df$Baz <- Foo2Baz(df$Year, df$Month, df$Foo)
# Expected Baz column: [1904, 1904, 1905, 1907] 
df$Baz
[1] 1904 1904 1905 1907
```

## PART 2: A lookup table

The more interesting transform that fails is like Foo2Baz above,
except it will call another function that looks up a value from some
other table.

```
# First we load a dataframe that backs the lookup operation. It's nice
# to keep as a dataframe, as opposed to matrix, for human inspection
# of cells.
lookup_table <- data.frame(
  Year=c(1900, 1901, 1902),
  Jan =c(  10,   20,   30),
  Feb =c( 100,  200,  200))

# Then we define a function to lookup a cell.
Lookup <- function(year, month) {
  return(lookup_table[
    year - 1899, # converts year to row index
    1 + month    # converts month to column, skipping 'Year'
  ])
}
# We expect a lookup of 1901-Feb to be 200
Lookup(1901, 2)
[1] 200
```

## PART 3: The transform function that calls a function.

```
# The goal is to transform Foo into new column Bar
# by looking up that case's Year and Month.
Foo2Bar <- function(year, month, foo) {
  return(foo + Lookup(year, month))
}

# We expect case 1 (1901,Feb,Foo=1) to have Bar=201
Foo2Bar(1901,2,1)
[1] 201

# We expect case 4 (1902,Jan,Foo=4) to have Bar=34
Foo2Bar(1902,1,4)
[1] 34
```

## PART 4: How to compute a new column for Bar?

Seems like we can now compute a Bar column using Foo2Bar just like
we used the simpler Foo2Baz:

```
df$Bar <- Foo2Bar(df$Year, df$Month, df$Foo)
df$Bar
    Feb Jan Feb.1 Jan.1
2   201  21   201    21
2.1 202  22   202    22
1   103  13   103    13
3   204  34   204    34
```

No column? Instead a matrix where rows and columns look like various inputs we sent to the Lookup() function?!

I've tried variations with do.call, apply,lapply,sapply and dplyr mutate. I seem to be simply missing something fundamental here.

Comment: df$Month is a vector, so you're returning several columns of Lookup, and several lines, that's expected

Comment: I think you want df$Bar <- unlist(apply(df,1,function(row){Lookup(row["year"],row["month"]}))

Comment: Thanks Moody, I as convinced that '$' or mutate() and whatever else should have been doing a "for each row..." when computing a new column. Also, in your answer it needs a close paren before the close curly brace, but that results in an error starting with " Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame")..." I read and reread apply, lapply and more a bunch of times and still haven't grokked what those functions are really doing, or the arguments, really!

Comment: I typed it from my phone without testing sorry :). This works :

Comment: df$Bar <- unlist(apply(df,1,function(row){Lookup(row["Year"],row["Month"])}))

Comment: apply functions are great, once you understand them you'll use them all the time, what I'm saying here is that I'm looking at df, by row (the second parameter = to 1, put 2 to say by column), then I apply a function by row, and this function returns the lookup of the year element and month element of the row. It returns a list sI unlist it to put it in yourdf$Bar array.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the arg-by-arg explanation, too. I will give apply family another try next time it seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need a `cbind`

```
Lookup <- function(year, month) {
   lookup_table[cbind(
           year - 1899, 
             1 + month)   
     ]
 }

Lookup(1901, 2)
#[1] 200
Foo2Bar(1901,2,1)
#[1] 201

df$Bar <- Foo2Bar(df$Year, df$Month, df$Foo)
df
#  Year Month Foo Bar
#1 1901     2   1 201
#2 1901     1   2  22
#3 1900     2   3 103
#4 1902     1   4  34
```

Comment: akrun, thanks! Your answer just needs to delete the close paren after close square brace in Lookup function! I'm still trying to understand exactly what happened here. Given two columns cbind will return the frame with them combine, ok. So your call makes two columns from simple expressions on those arguments for each row of df$Year and Month. Then the indexing: lookup_table[cbind(...)] does what? What different happened here?? :)

Comment: @dimfish  Thanks, I forgot to remove the closing braces after removing the `return(`  It is a row/column indexing method where the row and column vectors are `cbind` to create a matrix to extract the elements of the dataset based on the index